# printf colours not working from .bash_logout

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm trying to use [this lovely script](https://gist.github.com/danielrehn/d2e6f2129e5f853c3166#file-seeyouspacecowboy-sh) on logout from an Ubuntu box that I'm ssh'd into. If I invoke it manually, the colours are correct. However, whenever it's run from *.bash_logout*, every line is white and prefixed with the colour code:

```
\x1B[38;5;160;01m  .d8888b.  8888888888 8888888888      Y88b   d88P  .d88888b.  888     888  
\x1B[38;5;196;01m d88P  Y88b 888        888              Y88b d88P  d88P" "Y88b 888     888  
\x1B[38;5;202;01m  "Y888b.   8888888    8888888            Y888P    888     888 888     888  
\x1B[38;5;208;01m     "Y88b. 888        888                 888     888     888 888     888  
\x1B[38;5;214;01m       "888 888        888                 888     888     888 888     888  
\x1B[38;5;220;01m Y88b  d88P 888        888                 888     Y88b. .d88P Y88b. .d88P  
\x1B[38;5;226;01m  "Y8888P"  8888888888 8888888888          888      "Y88888P"   "Y88888P"
```

TERM is set to *xterm-256color* in both the VM and my host (OS X 10.11). I tried using `echo -e`, but all it did was prepend the colour string with an `-e`. Adding the contents of the script directly to *.bash_logout* works, though that seems messy. Thoughts?

Comment: Ok, changing the line in *.bash_logout* from `sh seeyou...` to `. seeyou...` or `source seeyou...` fixed it. I have no idea.

Comment: You can add this as an answer and mark it for other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In POSIX shell, you cannot use `\xXX` escapes in the `printf` command; you can only use octal notation. Using `.` or `source` executes your script by the current `bash` process instead of using a POSIX shell. `bash seeyou` would have worked as well.

A POSIX-compliant version of your script would change the first line to:

```
ESC_SEQ="\033[38;5;"
```

Of course, there is no particular reason to make code executed only from `.bash_logout` POSIX-compliant, since the file itself is specific to `bash`.